# Android "Nearby Share" Crash (was Native crash of com.android.bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby, prelaunch

I just ran the pre-launch testing on my app and the report shows a native crash of com.android.bluetooth.  I have never seen this before and have not had a lot of experience in reading the crash log.

Here is the log:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #01  pc 0x00000000006d27f8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+108)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000016ea8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+80)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000009de0  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+292)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000a22f14  /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (base::internal::Invoker<base::internal::BindState<bluetooth::hal::HciHalHidl::Start()::'lambda'()>, void ()>::RunOnce(base::internal::BindStateBase*)+32)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000a0ffd8  /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (bluetooth::os::Alarm::on_fire()+108)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000a115b8  /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (bluetooth::os::Reactor::Run()+584)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000a122b4  /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (bluetooth::os::Thread::run(bluetooth::os::Thread::Priority)+176)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000a1243c  /apex/com.android.btservices/lib64/libbluetooth_jni.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (bluetooth::os::Thread::*)(bluetooth::os::Thread::Priority), bluetooth::os::Thread*, bluetooth::os::Thread::Priority> >(void*)+68)
  #09  pc 0x00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #10  pc 0x00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)

Google Pixel 2 (Arm) (virtual)
1080x1920
Android 13 (SDK 33)
-
arm64-v8a
de_DE
```

The app does not use or support bluetooth.

It appears the error is from "Nearby Share" that uses Bluetooth and/or wifi. Here are the screen shots from the pre-launch report:

[image]

[image]

Is there something the app needs to do to support this? or can I disable?  It appears it is attempting to share an email the user is sending to report a problem or suggestion.

Comment: I am also facing this issue for the last few updates. Seems like an issue with Google test device.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I have not been able to resolve this.  I'm just about finished with y update and will try one more time.  If no success I will report to google and try to release anyway.  Have you been able to release your app with this error?

Comment: Wondering if it has to do with the API version. Mine happens on version 33 like yours. Please let us know in case you write google.

Comment: I did report but useless response with generic info about pre-release testing.  I responded that they did not address the crash and supporting documentation I provided.  Will see how they respond.

Comment: Here is the response from Google (finally):    

I understand that you have some issues about the devices used for Pre-launch testing scenarios. Unfortunately, we cannot support in controlling which devices are to be used or the issues encountered as our system uses a sophisticated algorithm which is intended to only display the simulation of running your app to these devices. Furthermore, if you think the issue cannot be replicated on your side or the devices specified, you may safely ignore this error as it won't have impacts in your app distribution in the Play console.

Comment: (continued): Alternatively, you may also control which devices you may want your app to be tested for Pre-launch reporting by defining custom tests in Firebase Test Lab. Please check this link for more details.

If you have any other questions about using the Play Console, please let me know and I’ll be happy to help.
Regards,
Kaye
Google Play Developer Support

Answer (score 0):

I submited a new release to Google Play this morning and I had the same issue on the prelaunch report.

Modifying the following lines in the build.gradle file seems to have solved it:

- compileSdk **34**
- implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: **'1.11.0'**
- implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:**1.2.1**'

Once done, you can rebuild your project and create the release.

Hope it would help.

P.

Comment: Tried, didn't worked, still got the same error on play console. I also tried Firebase robo-test because from what I've heard is that they use the same testing routine as play console tests, No issue in Robo tests, No issue in manual tests ,but play console gives this same error